# Basic compilation with MinGw standard 2011

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, mingw

I had an error unexpected during my program compilation.

*(I must use standard 2011 to `std::regex`.)*

In my MinGw cmd, I go to the folder in which my programme is, and write:

> g++ -Wall -c -std=c++0x main.cpp

here every thing is ok, but after when I write:

> g++ -Wall -o -std=c++0x main.exe main.o

it tell me :

> g++.exe: error: main.exe: No such file or directory

WHY ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're writing the switches in the wrong order. `-o` requires that the destination filename be after it.

Here, you've told GCC to link `main.exe` and `main.o` into the executable `-std=c++0x`, and `main.exe` doesn't even exist yet.

```
g++ -Wall -o -std=c++0x main.exe main.o
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ????????
```

Instead, tell it to link `main.o` into the executable `main.exe`, in C++0x mode:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -o main.exe main.o
#                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```